# How do I affect a visual block based on the first line?

Tags: vim

I'm trying to write my own function in vimscript in order to do block comments. Right now, I can only do it 2 ways: Block comment at the first character (beginning) of a line, or comment after the first non-space character for each individual line.

I would like it to function like in other editors like Visual studio, where the first line determines the "depth" of the comment, and then comments out the following lines based on the depth. The trouble is, I'm having trouble getting vim to apply to a whole block of visual select code rather than each line individually.

How I usually use this function is: visually highlight multiple lines, call `call AutoComment("","c")`, and the comment should appear.

```
# Example code:
def hello_world():
    for i in range(10):
        print(i)
    pass

# Way 1:
def hello_world():
#     for i in range(10):
#         print(i)
    pass

# Way 2:
def hello_world():
    # for i in range(10):
        # print(i)
    pass

# Way I want:
def hello_world():
    # for i in range(10):
    #     print(i)
    pass
```

**Solution**

In order to solve this, I think I need one of two things:

1. a way for the block to "remember" information about the first line and apply it to the rest
2. vimscript to get a list of the highlighted lines, and then use normal commands to apply the block commenting.

I have no idea how to do step 1 and am having trouble googling the right wording. Step 2 gives me `g`, `Ctrl-g`, but I do not know how to use that in vimscript.

Please let me know if there is a built-in vim function I can use, or if there's a better of solving the problem.

Vimscript about current way of commenting:

Way 1: commenting at the beginning of each line

```
function! AutoComment(comment_char, comment_boolean)
    let cur_filetype = &filetype

    if len(a:comment_char) != 0
        let comment_type = a:comment_char
    else
        let comment_type = GetCommentChar() " This changes depending on type of file
    endif

    let line=getline('.')

    if a:comment_boolean == 'c'
        let line = comment_type . ' ' . line
    elseif a:comment_boolean == 'u'
        " this does not work with double char comments like java/ts //
        if line[0:strlen(comment_type)-1] == comment_type
            let line = line[strlen(comment_type)+1:]
        endif
    endif

    call setline('.',line)
endfunction
```

Way 2: comment at the first character of the line

```
function AutoComment(comment_char, comment_boolean)
    if len(a:comment_char) == 0
        let comment_character =  GetCommentChar() " This changes depending on type of file
    else
        let comment_character = a:comment_char
    endif

    " get first character in a line.
    let move_to_first = "normal! mq^"
    execute move_to_first
    let current_char = matchstr(getline('.'), '\%' . col('.') . 'c.')
    " echo current_char
    let change_line = "normal! "
    if a:comment_boolean == 'c'
        " echo "line needs to be commented"
        let change_line = change_line . "i" . comment_character . " \<esc>"
    " elseif a:comment_boolean == 'u' || current_char == comment_character
    elseif a:comment_boolean == 'u'
        " echo "line is already commented"
        if current_char == comment_character
            let change_line = change_line . "xx \<esc>"
        endif
    endif
    let change_line = change_line . "`q"
    " echo change_line
    execute change_line
endfunction
```

Comment: How about giving [vim-commentary](https://github.com/tpope/vim-commentary) a try? It works in the way as you described.

Comment: I was trying to avoid plugins for things that are easy to be done in vimscript. If it turns out this is really hard to do on my own, I think I will end up using that plugin. I just feel like I'm "almost" there.

Comment: This is manifestly not "easy".

Answer (score 1):

The pain with this #3 is that, in general case, one must somehow deal with a mixture of spaces/tabs. For example, the 1st line has 4 spaces; the 2nd line has 1 tab = 8 spaces. Then the tab must be expanded, uncommenting later will probably not restore the original structure, etc. Of course, it does not apply to Python, but occurs in C and others (BTW. Vim source code uses such indentation). And having "a commenting function guaranteed to work with a single language only"... as a programmer I'd be ashamed.

I have the following in [my config](https://github.com/matveyt/vimfiles/blob/917b0af18db4177105098f7482a6f36f5943dbb1/autoload/misc.vim#L31) to toggle comments as of #1 or #2:

```
function! misc#comment(line1, line2, pi = &preserveindent) abort
    let l:lnum = nextnonblank(a:line1)
    if l:lnum == 0 || l:lnum > a:line2
        return
    endif
    let l:pat = printf('^\(\s*\)\(%s\)$', printf(escape(&cms, '^$.*~[]\'), '\(.*\)'))
    let l:sub = '\=empty(submatch(2)) ? submatch(0) : submatch(1)..submatch(3)'
    if getline(l:lnum) !~# l:pat
        let l:pat = a:pi ? '^\s*\zs.*' : '.*'
        let l:sub = printf(escape(&cms, '&\'), '&')
    endif
    call setline(l:lnum, map(getline(l:lnum, a:line2),
        \ {_, v -> empty(v) ? v : substitute(v, l:pat, l:sub, '')}))
endfunction

"""command! -range -bar -bang Comment call misc#comment(<line1>, <line2>, <bang>&pi)
"""nnoremap <silent>gcc :Comment!<CR>
"""xnoremap <silent>gc :Comment!<CR>
""" and so on...
```

At first it may look tempting to switch to #3 with simple `let l:pat = a:pi ? printf(' \{,%d}\zs.*', indent(l:lnum)) : ...` But it only works for spaces while dealing with bloody tabs kills all fun.

So I suggest leaving this to [NERDCommenter](https://github.com/preservim/nerdcommenter) and its monstrous 3000+ lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

I've come up with a hacky solution for now involving normal mode to do the commenting.

This seems good for me for now, but I definitely did not account for edge cases like Matt has suggested with Tabs and Spaces together.

I will use my custom solution for now, but if it will really break future programming languages, I will try NERDCommenter in the future as other people have suggested. For now it seems to work with python, typescript, and ansible yaml files, which is what I primarily work with on a daily basis.

This code gets the range of the visual select, then it goes to the first non-whitespace character in a line, and runs the normal mode command: `C-V` `[how many lines visually selected]` `j` `I` `[comment character]` `<esc>`.

For uncommenting: `C-V` `[how many lines visually selected]` `j` `[length of comment, #=1, //=2, etc]` `l` `x`.

My next goals are:

1. work with html files
2. after commenting/uncommenting, highlight the lines visually again.
3. Work on an autocomment system that based on the first line highlighted, will decide either to comment or uncomment out the rest.

Code:

```
function AutoComment(comment_char, comment_boolean) range
    if len(a:comment_char) == 0
        let comment_character =  GetCommentChar()
    else
        let comment_character = a:comment_char
    endif
    let vis_length = a:lastline - a:firstline
    let vis_length = vis_length . 'j'
    if vis_length == '0j'
        let vis_length = ''
    endif

    " get first character in a line.
    let move_to_first = "normal! mq^"
    execute move_to_first
    let line = getline('.')

    let first_nonspace = col('.') - 1
    let end_char = first_nonspace + strlen(comment_character) - 1
    let current_chars = line[first_nonspace : end_char]

    " let current_char = matchstr(getline('.'), '\%' . col('.') . 'c.')
    " echo current_char
    let change_line = "normal! \<C-V>" . vis_length
    if a:comment_boolean == 'c'
        let change_line = change_line . "I" . comment_character . " "
    elseif a:comment_boolean == 'u'
        if current_chars == comment_character
            let move_right = strlen(comment_character)
            let change_line = change_line . move_right . "lx"
        endif
    endif
    " Can add additional line here to highlight the previous lines
    " Can't decide a way that it'll work seamlessly, so ignore for now.
    let change_line = change_line . "\<esc>`q"
    " echo change_line
    execute change_line
endfunction
```